# Firefox OS app is not available from Hungary

Tags: firefox-os

I have created a Firefox OS application (a game) and it is approved by reviewers. It appears in the marketplace, but I can't download it to my phone because it says it is not available from my country (Hungary).

I have checked the country settings of the app, but Hungary (and some other countries: Germany, Spain, Greece, etc.) is grayed out, and I don't know what to do to make it available.

Has anyone any idea why it is not available from some countries?

Comment: Finally I found a solution. I've changed the app category from Game to Entertainment, and now every country is allowed.I think this is only a workaround, not the real solution :(

Comment: I think it could have to do with game content rating. Maybe for the grayed out countries a separate certification is needed for the game to be published there?

Answer (score 1):

I work on the Marketplace. This is currently a bug which I will work on fixing. You should be able to switch your app back to the Games category and have it available in Hungary tomorrow after the bug has been fixed.

Sorry for the inconveniences and thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it tomorrow.